# Why will the command not be sent to my DMs when I try and use it on my server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I expected this to send my custom help message (it is currently called testhelp instead of help as idk how to remove the built in help command) to the DMs of the person who used the testhelp command however it doesn't. I then tried to just send it to the server and it wouldn't send either. It is also not giving me any errors when I run the code.

[image: Code]

Comment: I believe you will find what you're looking for in this [example](https://gist.github.com/StudioMFTechnologies/ad41bfd32b2379ccffe90b0e34128b8b)

Comment: Do not screenshot code. Please copy and paste it into stack overflow so people can build on it and help you without having to squint at the small image or copy it out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to remove the default help command you do:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix,help_command=None)
```

Notice I set the help_command to None.

To send it to the DMs, use `await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)` or to send it to the server, just use `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`.

Hope this helps.